# Connect to ECL via .NET giving permission issue

Tags: core-service, sdl-tridion, ecl, c#

Trying to connect to Tridion via ECL WCF api but getting permission issue. Here is my code:

```
EndpointAddress eclServiceEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhoast:2660/ExternalContentLibrary/2012/netTcp");
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding
{
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
    ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
    {
        MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647,
        MaxArrayLength = 2147483647
    }
};
// ecl service client
var eclServiceClient = new SessionAwareEclServiceClient(binding, eclServiceEndpoint);
eclServiceClient.Impersonate(@"domain\user");
```

I am getting a permission error in the last line. I have added impersonation user to server, restarted COM+ services and IIS but nothing works.

What am I doing wrong? We are using Celum as ECL and we have DXA 1.9 (Web 8.5).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Tridion stack exchange.

Have you added impersonation user to CM configuration?

Here is the [SDL Docs link](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-D842FB96-B4B7-4FD6-B253-623F4F0A6A61) to do that.

Comment: yes, I think he did so because he added it in comment.

Comment: Hello, I found the solution for my problem. I forgot to restart SDL Service Host service after I added my username as Impersonation user, so the change was not taken. Thanks for your time.

Comment: In that case, please post your comment as an answer and 'accept' it so the question becomes closed